Estimate subgroup sizes with a a given OR including CI and total sample sizes
We are doing a meta-analysis using OR as the effect size, but on a limited number of trials. The data is a bit messy and some numbers are missing - at least for our purposes. I was wondering if there is a way to get the contingency tables if for one study we have the total number an and an OR with 95% CI. My guess would be that there is no single solution without the total sample size, but with this information I am not sure. I have scoured the literature but haven't found what we are looking for.

I found an answer to my question : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241384/how-to-derive-2x2-cell-counts-from-contingency-table-margins-and-the-odds-ratio
